# Environmental benefit of recycling small cables from electronics and holiday mini lights?

Tags: recycling

For electronics, I've watched some online videos explaining commercial shredding operations and some home based scrapper videos showing how they strip insulation from common household electrical wiring.

I fail to see how either shredding or compression-stripping methods can be used for net environmental benefit in recycling ribbon cables, string lights, etc.

Yet a local electronics recycling operation accepts string mini lights, the kind typically used as xmas decoration.

Edit: After manually removing the interior computer cables (seen in video), how does the facility separate the insulation from the conductor and is there a net environmental benefit? or do they send them to the landfill?

Comment: You point is that the common procedures to separate isolation from cables does not work for these small cables? Therefore, you are asking whether these cables can be recycled at all?

Comment: I suspect the main concern for the local recycler is not so much if it benefits the environment, but if it's economical.